# Google Sheets - Sum values based on date range

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I have a column of dates, column C, and a column of values, column G.  I want to be able to calculate monthly totals of column G.  I've poked around and found that you can use sumif or you can use a filter.  The filter method seems easier.  I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
=sum(filter(C3:C365,G3:G365>date(3/1/2016),G3:G365<date(3/31/2016)))
```

How can I check the dates in column C and then sum up the values from column G?

Thanks Rich

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=sumproduct(MONTH(C2:C) = 3,B2:B)
```

Three is the month number (March).

Comment: Hmm I tried this but it's returning a value that's 2.8 times larger than expected.  It should return 22.8 but it renders 65.45.

I've updated the columns to reflect my sheet
     =sumproduct(MONTH(F3:F) = 3,J3:J)

How can I get this to add up the values from the month of March?

Comment: I tested your formula =sumproduct(MONTH(F3:F) = 3,J3:J) and it worked. What does your data look like? Could you provide a sample?